# How get absolute path for tmp folder in windows 10 and nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows-10, tmp

I am trying to ru the following code (tmp lib [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tmp)):

```
const tmp = require('tmp')
tmp.dir(async (err, path, cleanupCallback) => {
    console.log(path)
}
```

Which outputs:

```
C:\Users\LONGUS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-13152HMljuIU3YKR0
```

How to make it output real path, like that `C:\Users\LONGUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-13152HMljuIU3YKR0`?

Answer (score 2):

The `tmp` package uses `os.tmpdir()` internally as the base path, [which on Windows returns the](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/64219741218aa87e259cf8257596073b8e747f0a/lib/os.js#L124) `TEMP`, `TMP`, or `(systemRoot + ''\\temp'')` directory paths.

The `TEMP` environment variable on Windows always defaults to using the DOS 8.3 "short" style path as a legacy for backwards compatibility with older software dating back to Windows 9x.

You have a few options:

1. Supply your own base path for the `tmp` Node module.
2. Use another module to resolve the 8.3-style filename into the full path.
3. Change the `TEMP` environment variable yourself to use the full path. You can do this on a per-process basis.